# MagickCore - stuck after ReadImage

Tags: c, imagemagick

I'm trying to learn how ImageMagick and C work, so I'm trying to load an image on disk, liquid resize it and save it back to disk, but I can't seem to make it work. The program doesn't necessarily freeze. (the caret in the console window blinks?)

But it doesn't progress any further either. This is my first time programming with C and I'm just kind of following along with what's on the MagickCore documentation. I don't see the problem?

Here is my code:

```
int main(void) 
{
    Image 
        *image;

    ImageInfo
        *imageinfo;

    ExceptionInfo
        *ei;

    char *path = "./";
    MagickCoreGenesis(path, MagickTrue);
    ei = AcquireExceptionInfo();

    // Load the image
    imageinfo = AcquireImageInfo();
    (void)CopyMagickString(imageinfo->filename, "image.png", MaxTextExtent);

    //(imageinfo->filename, _countof("image.png"), "image.png");

    image = ReadImage(imageinfo, ei);

    if (ei->severity != UndefinedException)
        CatchException(ei);
    if (image == (Image *)NULL)
        exit(1);

    size_t
        c, r;
    PointInfo pi;
    pi = image->resolution;
    c = pi.x / 100 * 50;
    r = pi.y / 100 * 50;

    image = LiquidRescaleImage(image, c, r, 0, 0, ei);
    strcpy_s(imageinfo->filename, _countof("img.png"), "img.png");
    WriteImage(imageinfo, image, ei);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's great that you're using ImageMagick to learn C, but I would highly recommend using `MagickWand` library over `MagickCore`. `MagickCore` is very low-level stuff, and you'll spend the majority of your time allocating/deallocating memory, copying buffers, and managing heap/stacks. `MagickWand` is the C-API that handles busy work, and allows you to focus on the task at hand. Here's what your code would look like w/ `MagickWand`.

```c
#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MagickWandGenesis();
    MagickBooleanType ok;
    MagickWand * wand;
    wand = NewMagickWand();
    // Error handle of wand is null.

    ok = MagickReadImage(wand, "image.png");
    // Error handle if not `ok'.

    size_t
        columns,
        rows;

    columns = MagickGetImageWidth(wand) / 100 * 50;
    rows = MagickGetImageHeight(wand)   / 100 * 50;

    ok = MagickLiquidRescaleImage(wand, columns, rows, 0, 0);
    // Error handle if not `ok'.

    MagickWriteImage(wand, "img.png");
    wand = DestroyMagickWand(wand);

    MagickWandTerminus();
    return 0;
}
```

A lot cleaner.

Now for the `MagickCore` code you provided. I believe there's some debugging needed to determine the issue. Try the following...

```c
Image
    *image,
    *newImage;

// ... Skip ahead ...

newImage = LiquidRescaleImage(image, c, r, 0, 0, ei);
if (newImage == (Image *)NULL) {
    // Error handle
} else {
    // Only replace `image' if LiquidRescaleImage was successful.
    ReplaceImageInList(&newImage, image);
}
```

Also debug the values of `c` & `r`. I'm speculating that `pi.x` & `pi.y` are zero values.

> But it doesn't progress any further either.

There's probably a missing NULL terminator in `imageinfo->filename`. Something else to check with a debugger.

Comment: Ah, yes. I already switched to MagickWand and that's real easy. I wanted to go the lowest level that's possible with ImageMagick, but it seems that I have more to learn. I couldn't debug the values of `c` and `r` because it didn't reach that. But if I touch MagickCore again (probably will), I'll check out the second solution. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!